# Can´t create files SFTP, SCP or through Plesk file manager

Tags: plesk

**Goal**: create domain, access via SFTP to upload some files and edit them.

**Steps done:**

- Created domain
- Created web hosting access user. Gave the user access to /bin/sh (also tried /bin/bash (chrooted)

I tested the user out by login through **ssh**. That works great, I can ssh into the new domain, I can delete stuff from **httpdocs** and create it too.

**What´s not working:**

- I tried accessing through FileZilla as per usual with **sftp://** protocol. Returns with the message:

> Connected to mynewdomain
>
> Error:    Received unexpected end-of-file from SFTP server

If I purposefully write the wrong password, it´ll catch that and fail on auth error, so I know the user authentication is working.

- I tried sending the data with scp command. I had to set the cipher cause that´s the one that the server allows.

  scp -c aes128-cbc some_stuff usercreated@mynewdomain:/

  usercreated's password:

  scp: /some_stuff: Permission denied
- I tried going to Plesk´s own File Manager and upload it through there. No dice, fails with an unhelpful message.

[image]

Found [this thread](https://talk.plesk.com/threads/ftp-is-not-working.334528/) in Plesk forum:

> Edit the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file
> Change PasswordAuthentication and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to
> yes Then scroll down until you see this line: Subsystem sftp
> /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server Comment out the above line, underneath it
> write this: Subsystem sftp internal-sftp Restart ssh /etc/init.d/ssh
> restart. Filezilla: set protocol to SFTP, set user and password
> previously configured in Plesk web interface (FTP accounts of your
> domains) No ssh keys are required for this connections.

I´ve done this and restarted the server. I then tried using **sftp** and I get this:

```
 sftp usercreated@blablanewdomain
 Unable to negotiate with ip_addresss_here port 22: no matching key exchange 
 method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman- 
 group1-sha1
 Connection closed.  
 Connection closed
```

I thought maybe there was a **server wide** blockage of sftp, so I went to **tools & settings** > **Security Policy** . But I see that the option **
Allow both secure FTPS and non-secure FTP connections** is selected.

I am out of ideas on this one, where did I mess up?